# When does Ember mirage use your real API and when does it use your mock API

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js, ember-cli-mirage

Ember mirage simulates your API Server to return "mock" data that can be used to test in your ember app. How do you know when Ember mirage will use your real API and when its using your mock API. How can you turn this on/off?

Answer (score 1):

By default, your Mirage server will run in test mode, and in development mode as long as the --proxy option isn’t passed. To change this default behavior, set enabled to either true or false in your ENV config.

```
// config/environment.js
...
if (environment === 'production') {
  ENV['ember-cli-mirage'] = {
     enabled: true //turns it on/off
  }
}
```

Sources:
[Ember-cli-mirage Configuration](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.2.x/configuration/)

Comment: You can use `this.passthrough('/addresses');` to also help decide when what is used.